# How big is a formula equivalent to a wff over $n$ variables with $2^n$ subformulas?

Tags: complexity-theory, logic, propositional-logic

**Definitions**: Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $\alpha$
and $\beta$ are propositional formulas,
then we'll call $\alpha$ and $\beta$ *independent* if neither implies the other,
or more formally, if $\lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$
and $\lnot(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$ are each satisfiable,
perhaps under different variable assignments.
The notation $|\phi|$ refers to the length of $\phi$ in characters.

We saw in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4775637/1884) to a previous question that if a
formula $\phi$ has $2^n$ independently varying propositional variables, then any formula logically equivalent to $\phi$ must be of length at least $2^n$. I'll call this answer $A$.

We now attempt to generalize that result from independent variables to independent formulas.
We are constrained to consider only those wffs $\phi$ that contain
$2^n$ pairwise independent formulas over $n$ variables. Syntactically, these formulas
$\alpha_i$ are constrained to occur at the leaf level of $\phi$, so that if a
variable were substituted for the formula, it would occur at the syntactic leaf
level of $\phi$. No other formula may occur at the leaf level of $\phi$. Neither $\phi$ nor any of the $\alpha_i$ is allowed to be
identically true or false.

**Question**: Can we then conclude that any formula $\varphi$ logically equivalent to $\phi$ must be of exponential length,
that is, if $\varphi \leftrightarrow \phi$, then $|\varphi| = \Omega(2^n)$?

**Argument**: We create $2^n$ new propositional variables

$$p_1,\ldots, p_{2^n}$$

and then define $2^n$ equivalences
$p_i \leftrightarrow \alpha_i$ for each of the independent $n$-place
formulas $\alpha_i$. At this point, we can just substitute the variable for the
corresponding formula and reduce the problem to the one solved in answer $A$.

Comment: @D.W.: Thanks for writing. No, I did not intend that.

Comment: @Someone: Thanks for your interest in my question. Were there specific terms you had in mind, or were you looking for a more general treatment?

Comment: @Someone: I've flagged your comment complete since I've addressed it here.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Consider the formula

$$\phi = \alpha_1 \lor \alpha_2 \lor \dots \lor \alpha_{2^n} \lor \text{True},$$

where the $\alpha_i$ are pairwise independent according to your definition.

$\phi$ meets the requirements of your question ($\phi$ contains $2^n$ pairwise independent formulas $\alpha_i$, all $\alpha_i$'s occur at the leaf level of $\phi$).

However $\phi$ is equivalent to $\psi = \text{True}$, which does not have exponential length.

Comment: Thanks for working on my question. I’ve edited the question to exclude situations I hadn't intended. 
Also, $\lnot(\alpha \rightarrow \text{True}) \equiv \text{False}$. Please let me know if I have made any mistake in marking the comments complete. Thanks

Comment: @ShyPerson, changing the question after you receive an answer, in a way that invalidates that existing answer, is generally frowned upon.  Instead, it's better to be very careful to state the question accurately the first time; and if you fail, to ask a new question.  I believe if you put a little thought into it, you should be able to find a way to modify my example with your updated requirements.  Hint: try a logical-or of two formulas, over variables.  Can you make the "or" be equivalent to $\text{True}$?